# Execute Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

I am using dynamic SQL to execute a query.

For this I have created this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MySP    
(    
   @StateId CHAR(3),    
   @DeptId VARCHAR(15),    
   @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)    
)    
AS    
BEGIN   
  DECLARE @Where NVARCHAR(500);    
  DECLARE @FinalQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)='';    

  SET @Where=' where emppersonal.stateid=Cast('''+@StateId+''' AS INT) AND emppersonal.deptid=LTRIM(RTRIM('''+@DeptId+'''))';    

  SET @FinalQuery = 'SELECT '+@Query+' '+@Where

  EXEC(@FinalQuery) 
END
```

I have executed that stored procedure with these params:

```
exec MySP '2','HPD0002',
'
 emppersonal.empfname,
 mdesigmast.designame AS CurrentDesignation,
 ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, pisempprofessional.appdate, 103),'') AS appdate,
 IDPT.deptname AS InitialJoinDept, 
 MO1.officeName,pisempprofessional.apporder, DSG.designame AS Designation, 
 mClassMaster.Name AS ClassName,
 mpisrecruitmentmode.Name AS RecruitmentMode,
 pisempprofessional.DesigName 

 FROM emppersonal 
 LEFT JOIN pisempprofessional ON emppersonal.stateid=pisempprofessional.stateid AND emppersonal.deptid=pisempprofessional.deptid And emppersonal.empcd=pisempprofessional.empcd 

 LEFT JOIN mdesigmast ON emppersonal.stateid=mdesigmast.stateid AND emppersonal.currdesig=mdesigmast.desigcode 

 LEFT JOIN mdeptmaster IDPT ON pisempprofessional.stateid=IDPT.stateID AND pisempprofessional.InitialJoiningdeptid=IDPT.deptid 
 LEFT JOIN mofficemaster MO1 ON pisempprofessional.stateid=MO1.stateid AND pisempprofessional.officeid=MO1.officeid 
 LEFT JOIN mdesigmast DSG  ON pisempprofessional.StateID=DSG.StateID AND pisempprofessional.iphdesg=DSG.desigcode 
 LEFT JOIN mClassMaster ON pisempprofessional.iphclass=mClassMaster.ID  
 LEFT JOIN mpisrecruitmentmode ON  pisempprofessional.modeofrec=mpisrecruitmentmode.id
```

'

and when I execute that procedure, I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
>   Incorrect syntax near '2'.
>
> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '))'.

How to resolve above errors?

Thanks

Comment: Change `ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, pisempprofessional.appdate, 103),'')` to `ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, pisempprofessional.appdate, 103),'''')`

Comment: Thank You @wewesthemenace.. :). You can post it as answer..

Comment: You can just accept @Mackan's answer as we're just saying the same thing.

Comment: I would just like to add that you don't have to cast values when constructing your query string... So `SET @Where=' where emppersonal.stateid=Cast(''' + @StateId + ''' AS INT)...` can easily be replaced by `SET @Where=' where emppersonal.stateid=' + @StateId + '...'` unless this `@StateId` can be other things and not just numbers. I would also suggest to change its type from `char(3)` to `varchar(3)` so the number will always be just as long as it needs to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you do in other places, you need to use double apostrophes:

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, pisempprofessional.appdate, 103),'''')
```

That should do it

> The apostrophe, or single quote, is a special character in SQL that specifies the beginning and end of string data. This means that to use it as part of your literal string data you need to escape the special character. With a single quote this is typically accomplished by doubling your quote.

Answer (score 0):

Like [@Mackan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1996783/mackan) mentioned

> The apostrophe, or single quote, is a special character in SQL that
>   specifies the beginning and end of string data. This means that to use
>   it as part of your literal string data you need to escape the special
>   character. With a single quote this is typically accomplished by
>   doubling your quote.

So Change in your `Param` from

```
exec MySP '2','HPD0002',
'emppersonal.empfname,
 mdesigmast.designame AS CurrentDesignation,
 /*Change the below line*/
 ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, pisempprofessional.appdate, 103),'') AS appdate,
 IDPT.deptname AS InitialJoinDept, 
 MO1.officeName,pisempprofessional.apporder, DSG.designame AS Designation, 
 mClassMaster.Name AS ClassName,
 mpisrecruitmentmode.Name AS RecruitmentMode,
 pisempprofessional.DesigName 

 FROM emppersonal 
 LEFT JOIN pisempprofessional ON emppersonal.stateid=pisempprofessional.stateid AND emppersonal.deptid=pisempprofessional.deptid And emppersonal.empcd=pisempprofessional.empcd 

 LEFT JOIN mdesigmast ON emppersonal.stateid=mdesigmast.stateid AND emppersonal.currdesig=mdesigmast.desigcode 

 LEFT JOIN mdeptmaster IDPT ON pisempprofessional.stateid=IDPT.stateID AND pisempprofessional.InitialJoiningdeptid=IDPT.deptid 
 LEFT JOIN mofficemaster MO1 ON pisempprofessional.stateid=MO1.stateid AND pisempprofessional.officeid=MO1.officeid 
 LEFT JOIN mdesigmast DSG  ON pisempprofessional.StateID=DSG.StateID AND pisempprofessional.iphdesg=DSG.desigcode 
 LEFT JOIN mClassMaster ON pisempprofessional.iphclass=mClassMaster.ID  
 LEFT JOIN mpisrecruitmentmode ON  pisempprofessional.modeofrec=mpisrecruitmentmode.id'
```

to

```
exec MySP '2','HPD0002',
'emppersonal.empfname,
 mdesigmast.designame AS CurrentDesignation,
 ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, pisempprofessional.appdate, 103),'''') AS appdate,
 IDPT.deptname AS InitialJoinDept, 
 MO1.officeName,pisempprofessional.apporder, DSG.designame AS Designation, 
 mClassMaster.Name AS ClassName,
 mpisrecruitmentmode.Name AS RecruitmentMode,
 pisempprofessional.DesigName 

 FROM emppersonal 
 LEFT JOIN pisempprofessional ON emppersonal.stateid=pisempprofessional.stateid AND emppersonal.deptid=pisempprofessional.deptid And emppersonal.empcd=pisempprofessional.empcd 

 LEFT JOIN mdesigmast ON emppersonal.stateid=mdesigmast.stateid AND emppersonal.currdesig=mdesigmast.desigcode 

 LEFT JOIN mdeptmaster IDPT ON pisempprofessional.stateid=IDPT.stateID AND pisempprofessional.InitialJoiningdeptid=IDPT.deptid 
 LEFT JOIN mofficemaster MO1 ON pisempprofessional.stateid=MO1.stateid AND pisempprofessional.officeid=MO1.officeid 
 LEFT JOIN mdesigmast DSG  ON pisempprofessional.StateID=DSG.StateID AND pisempprofessional.iphdesg=DSG.desigcode 
 LEFT JOIN mClassMaster ON pisempprofessional.iphclass=mClassMaster.ID  
 LEFT JOIN mpisrecruitmentmode ON  pisempprofessional.modeofrec=mpisrecruitmentmode.id'
```